# Can JAVI BROTHERS in JAVI BROTHERS MOVIES be considered as an adjective

Tags: word-choice, difference, word-usage, possessives

Which would be the ideal choice, literal option:

A JAVI BROTHERS MOVIES

A JAVI BROTHER'S MOVIES

A JAVI BROTHERS' MOVIES

Comment: The *Javi Brothers* in *a Javi Brothers movie* or *Javi Brothers movies* is a [noun adjunct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you can't say "a movies". It's either "a (...) movie" if it's one movie, or "(...) movies" when there's more. Let's assume the second.

Otherwise, all three are correct, but in different contexts.

You'd say "Javi brothers' movies" when referring to the actual group of people who make the films. Like "Wachowski brothers' movies", or "Coen brothers' movies".

You'd say "Javi Brothers movies" when "Javi Brothers" is a corporation or otherwise a singular entity - "Javi Brothers" then functions as an attributive noun. Compare "Warner Brothers movies".

You'd say "Javi brother's movies" when one of the brothers has gone out and made films *on his own*. So, for example, if Joel Coen decided to ditch Ethan, you could refer to his films as "Coen brother's movies". It would be a somewhat odd construction, but correct.

That's all, of course, assuming that we're taking about *creating* movies, not *owning* them - for example, on DVDs :)

Comment: you wouldn't say "has went out" you would say "has gone out"

Comment: @Octopus good catch, corrected.